# Using Netbeans Debugger with an Included Library

Tags: java, netbeans, debugging, breakpoints

Howdy folks!  My very first StackOverflow post.  Most exciting!

In NetBeans 6.9.1, I've created a wrapper project around an existing project in order to display a friendly GUI front-end.  Since our users should never see this GUI it really has no business in the original project.  The original project is included as a named Library of the wrapper project via the Project Properties > Libraries tab.

I set a breakpoint in the original project, then run the wrapper project in Debug mode via Debug > Debug Main Project.  When I trigger a code path that definitely takes me through the breakpoint (I know because the breakpoint is on a println() statement), the debugger console prints:

```
LineBreakpoint ErrorHandler.java : 164 successfully submitted.
```

But does not break.  Breakpoints set in the wrapper project work correctly.

After a little googling, I made certain that the "generate debugging info" boxes are checked in both projects' Project Properties > Build > Compiling dialog and that sources are attached for the original project.  I've also done a Clean/Build of the original project after the breakpoint was set, just for good measure.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  Is there a cleaner way to set this up?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. I'm trying to set breakpoints in the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration class and it is giving  me a headache. May try to recompile hibernate from source...oh, joy!